# What satellites were launched into a polar orbit from Cape Canaveral in the 1950s and 1960s?

Tags: history, polar-orbit, cape-canaveral, launch-trajectories

Historically, most launches from U.S. soil that have headed into a polar or near-polar orbit have been launched from Vandenberg Air Force Base in California. However, in a recent article written by James Dean of Florida Today, titled "[Southbound? Cape rockets may fly new path toward poles](http://www.floridatoday.com/story/tech/science/space/2017/12/31/southbound-cape-rockets-may-fly-new-path-toward-poles/975027001/)", in which the possibility of flying into a polar orbit from Florida is now considered feasible, that in the early days of the space race, launches were indeed conducted on polar trajectories from Florida:

> Cape launches most often head east to send satellites on their way around the equator. Polar trajectories have been avoided since a 1960 Navy launch inadvertently dropped a Thor rocket stage on Cuba, reportedly killing a cow.

Do we have a list of these satellites, their launching vehicle, and the date of their launch? Ideally, please only cite first hand sources, not forums.

Comment: Again, wiki listings like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1960_in_spaceflight may be a good way to start.

Comment: This link https://www.quora.com/Did-debris-from-Skylab-really-kill-a-cow pinpoints the cow-killing launch as 30 Nov 1960, which seems to be Transit 3A http://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/transit-3.htm As you may see this is not a polar launch and earlier polar satellites were already launched from Vandenberg

Comment: fyi I've just asked [What were the two circa 1965 semi-polar missions launched from Cape Canaveral?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41579/12102)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [Zarya](http://www.zarya.info/Diaries/Launches/Launches.php?year=1960), which lists all attempted launches and the orbits of all successful launches, there was never a successful launch from Canaveral to polar orbit. The highest inclination I saw was the Transit 2A, which had a 67 degree inclination.

It seems likely the cow killing incident was the Transit 3A, presumably which would have been launched in to a similar orbit.

Bottom line, I suspect the only remotely polar launches from Canaveral thus far have been the Transit 2A and 3A. The Transit 1A/1B were at an inclination of about 50 degrees.

I should add that I looked at each of the failed orbits to see if I could determine if they would have been a higher inclination by looking at the replacement launches, and couldn't find anything.

I suspect the article should have stated southward launches, as opposed to the normal North or Northeast launches that typically happen from Canaveral.