# What were the two circa 1965 semi-polar missions launched from Cape Canaveral?

Tags: nasa, history, military, international-politics, united-states

Teslarati's [SpaceX sets date for first Florida launch of its kind in more than half a century](https://www.teslarati.com/spacex-florida-first-polar-launch-half-a-century/) says

> That November 1960 launch thus shut down East Coast polar launches to avoid overflying Cuba and raising the country’s ire near the height of Cold War tensions. **It’s believed that the Cape actually launched two more semi-polar missions in the mid-1960s, some five years later**, but the fact remains that SpaceX’s prospective March 30th, 2020 launch will mark the United States’ first East Coast launch in more than half a century.

I believe that the November 1960 launch is described in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27650/12102).

**Question:** What were the two circa 1965 semi-polar missions launched from Cape  Canaveral?

Comment: does it really say " will mark the United States’ first East Coast launch in more than half a century" ? Lol.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Ya, they left "of its kind" out of that sentence.

Comment: Too busy thinking up new superlatives, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These missions might be TIROS 9 and 10. These were sun-synchronous meteorological missions launched on Thor-Delta C launchers from Cape Canaveral LC-17A and LC-17B respectively:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIROS-9
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIROS-10

Found in [Celestrak's SATCAT](https://celestrak.org/satcat/) by looking for international designator "1965-" and sorting by launch site.

Comment: Good find! Likely candidates indeed.